# How to manipulate large data sets in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, data-storage

As far as I know, in iOS we can keep data in JSON files, .plist or .xml files, NSUserDefaults (which is basically a .plist file), SQLite database, or Core Data (which can be set to have different data stores, but usually we use .sqlite files).

I am currently supposed to make my app be able to work with tens of thousands of records, and I am using Core Data. The thing is that my client told me Core Data is probably not the best solution for large datasets, and I am confused because as far as I know, if we have so many records we should obviously not keep them all in memory (in `NSMutableArray` or other collection objects), and Core Data seems to be the best and fastest way to implement all the functionality.

Please let me know if you have the same problem in the past and which solution you chose.

Comment: We use sqlite. I'm not sure this belongs on this forum, though.

Comment: Basically sqlite is the persistent store in the my case too. I know generally using Core Data with .sqlite as the persistent store is faster than using sqlite directly. But I am wondering, is there any other method than using sqlite which would be faster.

Comment: Dear Ian, are you the one who down-voted the question? Please let me know to which forum should it be posted than if not on this one?

Comment: I did not downvote this question.

Answer (score 1):

I have used core data for a 64 thousand object database, worked perfectly as expected.  Not sure exactly what you are trying to do but core data will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience, Kris!